# Who is flying in this picture from Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, character-identification, avengers-age-of-ultron

I was taking a closer look at the *Avengers: Age of Ultron* poster and I noticed someone flying in on the top left corner. Who is this new character? What do they have to do with the battle against Ultron?

[image]

Comment: -1 for no hand-drawn circles

Comment: @KSmarts -.- You're welcome to add your amazing hand-drawn circles by editing.

Comment: +1 to undo the minus one for no hand drawn circles.  (Although hopefully that was a joke.)

Comment: @msouth: Hmm it's not your job to "undo" other people's right to vote!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I totally agree!  I would certainly never do anything to undo a person's right to vote!  My job is actually to be a software development manager. If my job was to undo a person's right to vote, I would most certainly get a different job, or, at the very least, start secretly working against whoever my employer was, by appearing to undo people's right to vote, while actually secretly working to increase their right to vote.  And by doing this I would be doubly virtuous because I would be taking the money of whatever evil entity hired people to undo people's right to vote!

Comment: @msouth: That sounds awesome!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Now that the film has been released, we know who this character is.

This character is

> **the Vision**, played by Paul Bettany

In the comics, their relation to Ultron is that

> Vision was created by Ultron to prove that he could create life as well (Ultron himself being a synthetic lifeform). Vision is an android, and speculation suggests that it may be a spinoff of JARVIS come to the Avengers's aid.

In the movie,

> Vision’s body is created by Ultron as a final stage of his evolution; a final body for him. The body is created as a combination of genetic material and Vibranium. However, before Ultron can fully upload his mind into the body, it is stolen by the Avengers, and Stark and Banner load it with a modified version of JARVIS as a consciousness.

Comment: Interesting bit of info about the actor who will portray the flying character, they have never seen any of the MCU movies they have appeared in. They don't like comic books movies!

Comment: @Daft: They're apparently also pretty grumpy about actually having to show up in person for filming. :-P

Comment: haha... poor fella, it's a tough life I'm sure! :D

Comment: I have nothing but respect for the man who goes home each night to Jennifer Connelly.

Comment: @Daft:  What's with the singular 'they' for a specific person of known gender?

Comment: @ThePopMachine this comment was posted before the movie came out, I was trying to avoid giving away any information about the character. This obviously annoys you, but we try to avoid spoilers whenever possible.

Comment: Paul Bettany doesn't like super-hero movies, yet he starred in "Legion"? Some things I'll never understand . . .